# Restore very old photograph

Tags: image-editing, restoration

I have a very old photograph that is scanned from a document dating to 1869. I do not have access to the source document.

The image itself is very badly sampled and looks almost completely black. Can anyone suggest some techniques/processes I could apply to help me try and recover some detail from the image?

I realise it's entirely possible that no detail now exists.

The image below is what I'm dealing with (extracted from a larger document): [image]

Comment: I hate to say it, but I very highly doubt anything can be done with that image.  There is _way_ too little detail left, from what I saw when I tried messing with it in Photoshop

Comment: What have you tried that didn't work? Please show us your efforts&mdash;it increases your chances for a good answer. Thanks!